# в театре имени ее самой/самой себя

Tags: управление

Будьте добры, подскажите: она играла в театре имени ее самой/самой себя?

Answer (score 1):

Есть выражение ["В театре своего имени"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LcTSBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA433&lpg=PA433&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=B2DYqp1ub2&sig=ACfU3U3zKr0pLodb1VQQoDuLyTcuwDbS5A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE6q_8j73kAhWNgVwKHfAtBg8Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22&f=false).

[Источник:](http://www.w-shakespeare.ru/library/vilyam-shekspir-issledovaniya-i-materialy12.html)

> В 20-х и 30-х годах в печати не раз появлялись сообщения о том, что
>   Мейерхольд предполагает поставить «Гамлета» в театре своего
>   имени.

Answer (score 1):

> Будьте добры, подскажите: она играла в театре имени ее самой/самой
>   себя?

Грамматически оба варианта допустимы. Но "имени себя самой" и тем более "самой себя" звучит пренебрежительно, а "её самой" может быть понято иронически. Так что в очередной раз убеждаюсь, что без контекста вопросы по стилистике лучше не задавать.

(+)
Вариант "своего имени" безусловно хорош, когда речь идет о строгой публицистике. В разговорной речи вызывает ощущение излишней помпезности, напыщенности.

> Первый президент Казахстана Нурсултан Назарбаев вручил президенту
>   России орден своего имени

Комично звучит, не находите?

*Ко всему прочему я бы не назвал это выражение устоявшимся. 
Но это другая тема, здесь, наверное, не принципиально.*